# Average length and entropy of a code from a probabilistic source

Tags: information-theory

I'm trying to do this exercise but I have some doubts.

> A binary memoryless source emits the symbols 0 and 1 with probability 0.8 and 0.2 respectively.
>   It encodes three blocks messages: 000 is encoded with 0; any other xyz block with 1xyz.
>
> 1. The obtained code is UD?
> 2. It is instantaneous?
> 3. Calculate the average length (binary symbol) of the code and compare that to the entropy of the source.

The code is UD and instantaneous.
I tried to calculate the average length and the entropy in this way:

[image]
[image]

The question marks indicate that I don't know how to go on to make the calculations.

Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot!

---

This is what I've done:

$p(000) = 0.8^3 = 0.512$

$p(001) = 0.8^2 + 0.2 = 0.84$

$p(010) = 0.8^2 + 0.2 = 0.84$

$p(011) = 0.8 + 0.2^2 = 0.84$

$p(100) = 0.8^2 + 0.2 = 0.84$

$p(101) = 0.8 + 0.2^2 = 0.84$

$p(110) = 0.8 + 0.2^2 = 0.84$

$p(111) = 0.2^3 = 0.008$

$\bar{l} = \sum_{i}^{ } l_i p(a_i) $
$        = 1\cdot p(000) + 4\sum_{x^{(3)}\neq 000}^{ } p(x^{(3)})$
$        = 0.512 + 4[3Pr(\#1=1) + 3Pr(\#1=2) + 1Pr(\#1=3)]$
$        = 0.512 + 4[3\cdot 0.2+3\cdot 0.2^2+0.2^3]=3.424$

$H(X) = -\sum_{i}^{ } p(a_i) \log_{2}p(a_i)$
$= -0.512 \log_{2} 0.512 -6(0.84 \log_{2} 0.84) -0.008 \log_{2} 0.008 = 1.81$

It's right? I think is not..

---

$p(000) = 0.8^3 = 0.512$

$p(001) = 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2 = 0.128$

$p(010) = 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2 = 0.128$

$p(011) = 0.8 \cdot 0.2^2 = 0.032$

$p(100) = 0.8^2 \cdot 0.2 = 0.128$

$p(101) = 0.8 \cdot 0.2^2 = 0.032$

$p(110) = 0.8 \cdot 0.2^2 = 0.032$

$p(111) = 0.2^3 = 0.008$

$\bar{l} = \sum_{i}^{ } l_i p(a_i) $
$        = 1\cdot p(000) + 4\sum_{x^{(3)}\neq 000}^{ } p(x^{(3)})$
$        = 0.512 + 4[3Pr(\#1=1) + 3Pr(\#1=2) + 1Pr(\#1=3)]$
$        = 0.512 + 4[3\cdot 0.2+3\cdot 0.2^2+0.2^3]=3.424$

$H(X) = -\sum_{i}^{ } p(a_i) \log_{2}p(a_i)$
$= -0.512 \log_{2} 0.512 -3(0.128 \log_{2} 0.128) -3(0.032 \log_{2} 0.032) -0.008 \log_{2} 0.008 = 2.16$

I don't know what else to do, I feel very stupid.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{x\ne 000} p(x)$ is the probability of at least one 1 in the word. It's easy to break it according the number of ones ($\#1$) in $x$
$$=3 \Pr[\#1 =1] + 3\Pr[\#1=2] + 1\Pr[\#1=3]= 0.488$$

Which is indeed equal to $(1-(p_0)^3)$ as you wrote yourself.

The entropy is being computed similarly. Just plug in $\Pr(x)$ for any possible $x\in \{0,1\}^3$. BTW, your formula is written incorrectly (I assume it is a typo). Should be
$$ H(X) = -\sum_{a_i} p(a_i) \log_2(p(a_i)).$$

Comment: Thank for the reply. How did you get 0.488?

Comment: @four can you tell what is $p_0$?

Comment: $p_0$ is the probability of the sequence $000$. I don't understand how I should calculate it, I just know that $p(0) = 0.8$, then $p(000)$ is $0.8^3$ or $3*0.8$ or something else?

Comment: @four, Actually $p_0$ is the probability of seeing a "0", which is 0.8 as you say. The probability for seeing 000 is $p(000)=p_0^3$. This should fully answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I modified the main message with the steps I did to solve the exercise. Could you tell me if I have done in the right way?

Comment: @four recall that $\Pr[A \text{ and } B] = \Pr[A] \times \Pr[B]$. (assuming independent $A$, $B$)

Comment: I changed again the main message. I changed the $p(***)$ and entropy calculation.